# Losing HttpContext with async await in ASP.NET Identity GetRolesAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-identity

This is more of an async/await question than ASP.NET Identity. I am using Asp.Net Identity, and have a custom UserStore, with a customized GetRolesAsync method.  The UserManager is called from a WebApi controller.

```
public class MyWebApiController {
    private MyUserManager manager = new MyUserManager(new MyUserStore());
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<bool> MyWebApiMethod(int x) {
        IList<string> roles = await manager.GetRolesAsync(x);
        return true;
    }
}
public class MyUserManager : UserManager<MyUser, int> {

    // I do not implement a custom GetRolesAsync in the UserManager, but 
    // from looking at the identity source, this is what the base class is doing:

    // public virtual async Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TKey userId)
    // {
    //     ThrowIfDisposed();
    //     var userRoleStore = GetUserRoleStore();
    //     var user = await FindByIdAsync(userId).WithCurrentCulture();
    //     if (user == null)
    //     {
    //         throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.UserIdNotFound,userId));
    //     }
    //     return await userRoleStore.GetRolesAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
    // }
}

public class MyUserStore {
    public async Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TUser user) {

        // I need HttpContext here and it is NULL. WHY??
        var currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; // NULL!

         var query = from userRole in _userRoles
                    where userRole.UserId.Equals(userId)
                    join role in _roleStore.DbEntitySet on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
                    select role.Name;

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Why is context null in MyUserStore.GetRolesAsync? I thought await passed the context down? I've stepped through other async methods in MyUserStore and they all have the correct context, and the code seems virtually identical.

Comment: What is the target framework version you're using?

Comment: 4.5.1 in project settings,  - web.config: <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>

Comment: Try setting `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` to `true` in your app.config

Comment: Weird. Are you calling `Task.Run` anywhere?

Comment: Not in my code. I think I have the same Identity source I'm using,but I could reflect it just in case.

Comment: I wonder if `WithCurrentCulture` is preventing the regular SyncCtx capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turns out to be a property of `TaskExtensions.WithCurrentCulture`. These are the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn857449(v=vs.113).aspx) for EF, but they apply for ASP.NET Identity as well:

> Configures an awaiter used to await this Task **to avoid marshalling the continuation back to the original context**, but preserve the current culture and UI culture.

This causes the synchronization context not to marshal, which causes `HttpContext` to be `null`.

Here is the relevant part from [the source](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.2.0-alpha1-140802/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/TaskExtensions.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core):

```
public void UnsafeOnCompleted(Action continuation)
{
    var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    var currentUiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

    // This part is critical.
    _task.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().UnsafeOnCompleted(() =>
    {
        var originalCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        var originalUiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentUiCulture;
        try
        {
            continuation();
        }
        finally
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = originalCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = originalUiCulture;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @user Definitely. At least it's documented :)